Define order of record types shown on new Case creation
I have created 3 record types on the case:

When I try to create case, Record Type options are shown like below:

I check that the sequence is not in as per alphabetical order. Not as per CreatedDate order.
How can I configure Case, So the record type options are shown in below sequence:
My Record Type 1
My Record Type 2
My Record Type 3

See Idea (been out there since 2008).  Which of the record types is the default for the user?
